# How I can make a never ending If Else statement program?

Tags: java

How I can make a never ending If Else statement program guys? This is a simple program I have made using If and Else statemen (i have put things as x)

```
    package x;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class x {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input;
        System.out.println("How are you?");
        input = in.nextLine();

        if(input.contains("good")){
            System.out.println("That's great. ");

        }
        else if(input.equals("bad")){
            System.out.println("Bad? Yikes!");
        }
        else { 

        System.out.println("Alright");
        }
        input = in.nextLine();
        if(input.contains("what is the time"))
        { System.out.println("It is currently x");
        }


    }

}
```

What I want to do is I want to make the if else statement above never end I want to use these statements everytime. I mean after you input to the next line, the statement above cannot be used again. What I want to do is I want to reuse the statement, say "what is the time" again after I have used it in the next input. I want to create a loop. What I have to do? Sorry if you can't understand, I am very new to JAVA :v

Comment: How about `while (true) { .. }`?

Comment: Try to follow some more tutorials before asking these questions, because this is very basic.

Answer (score 4):

You need these set of statements in an infinite loop. What else you need is a `termination` step to break this infinite loop. Assuming that you want to break this when you enter "terminate" string, you can do something like this:

```
System.out.println("How are you?");
while(true) {
    input = in.nextLine();

    /* Specify Terminate Condition */
    if(input.contains("terminate")) {
         break;
    } else if(input.contains("good")){
        System.out.println("That's great. ");
    } else if(input.equals("bad")){
       System.out.println("Bad? Yikes!");
    } else { 
       System.out.println("Alright");
    }

    input = in.nextLine();
    if(input.contains("what is the time")) { 
       System.out.println("It is currently x");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it quite worked but after completing the loop it again showed me the first statement which is "How are you". I don't want it show that, I want it to wait for the instructions.

Comment: Move the `sysout()` outside loop then. Solution Updated!